# XQuery if statement

Tags: xquery

I have problem with XQuery. I've spend on this proble a lot of time, and I can't make it work :( Here is my XML book node:

```
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

That's what i want to achive:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b>XML Developer's Guide</b>
      </td>
      <td class="author">Gambardella, Matthew</td>
      <td class="genre">Computer</td>
      <td class="price">44.95</td>
      <td class="priceVat">55.29</td>
      <td class="publish_date">2000-10-01</td>
      <td class="description">An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my XQuery code:

```
for $book in doc("/home/kuba/mgr/pliki/books.xml")//book
order by number($book/price) descending
   return
     <tr>
       <td><b>{ string($book/title) }</b></td>
       {
         for $value in $book/*
         return if($value != $book/title and name($value) != 'price') then
            <td class="{name($value)}">{$value/text()}</td>
           else
            if(name($value) = 'price') then
                <td class="{name($value)}">{$value/text()}</td>
                <td class="{name($value)}Vat">{$value/text()*1.23}</td>
            else ()
       }
     </tr>
```

The problem is in this line:

```
        <td class="{name($value)}Vat">{$value/text()*1.23}</td>
```

Here is my error message:

```
Engine name: Saxon-PE XQuery 9.5.0.2
Severity: fatal
Description: XPST0003: expected "else", found name "class"
Start location: 17:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPST0003
```

How i can make it? Is possible to format number in XQuery 1.0, i read that th is not possible but I want to make sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your `then` clause you return a sequence of `<td>` elements, but they need to be wrapped in parentheses and separated by a comma:

```
if(name($value) = 'price') then
  (<td class="{name($value)}">{$value/text()}</td>,
  <td class="{name($value)}Vat">{$value/text()*1.23}</td>)
else ()
```

Comment: Oh, earlier i try without the comma :D thanks that works fine.